# Filtering an array on nested values by using values from another array

Tags: python

I have this array of 3 objects.
The parameter that interests me is "id", that is nested into "categories" attribute.

```
list = [
  {
    "title": "\u00c9glise Saint-Julien",
    "distance": 1841,
    "excursionDistance": 1575,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "300-3200-0030",
        "name": "\u00c9glise",
        "primary": true
      },
      {
        "id": "300-3000-0025",
        "name": "Monument historique"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Sevdec",
    "distance": 2250,
    "excursionDistance": 301,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "700-7600-0322",
        "name": "Station de recharge",
        "primary": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "SIEGE 27",
    "distance": 2651,
    "excursionDistance": 1095,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "700-7600-0322",
        "name": "Station de recharge",
        "primary": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I have these two arrays that contain ids:

```
mCat1 = ["300-3000-0000","300-3000-0023","300-3000-0030","300-3000-0025","300-3000-0024","300-3100"] # macro cat1 = tourism
mCat2 = ["400-4300","700-7600-0322"]
```

I need to filter "list" on "mCat1" in order to extract in a new variable the object(s) that have at least one "id" that matches those in "mCat1".
Then I need to do the same with "mCat2".

In this example the expected result would be:

```
mCat1Result = [{
    "title": "\u00c9glise Saint-Julien",
    "distance": 1841,
    "excursionDistance": 1575,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "300-3200-0030",
        "name": "\u00c9glise",
        "primary": true
      },
      {
        "id": "300-3000-0025",
        "name": "Monument historique"
      }
    ]
  }]


mCat2Result = [{
    "title": "Sevdec",
    "distance": 2250,
    "excursionDistance": 301,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "700-7600-0322",
        "name": "Station de recharge",
        "primary": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "SIEGE 27",
    "distance": 2651,
    "excursionDistance": 1095,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "700-7600-0322",
        "name": "Station de recharge",
        "primary": true
      }
    ]
  }]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this? I am able to do it using loops but it is very resource dependent on large datasets.

Comment: Can you show what you've done using loops? How large is your dataset? How much time did it take, and how did you measure that?

Comment: The dataset isn't large, it is about 200 objects but each one has a lot more data in them in comparaison to the ones in this example. Process time is a few seconds wich is quite poor. The code has been changed and currently not working as I have been playing arround with it. I am currently running the code on a jupyter notebook, in a separate cell so that i can have a rough estimation of the time it takes to compute.